# Crash of Starcraft 2 while downloading it from PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I have an issue with installing Sc2 (Starcraft 2, a videogame) on PlayOnLinux using the Starcraft-II-Setup.exe which is a file downloaded from Battlenet on internet.
There appears a screen which says:
               "Wine Crash
Internal errors, received parameters not valid".
I don't know what's the problem about, I have installed PlayOnLinux and Wine from Ubuntu Software Center and then tried to download Sc2 from PlayOnLinux.

I've seen on Youtube people playing Starcraft 2 on Ubuntu so I think that's possible to run it, on Ubuntu..

What should I do?

Ps: My Ubuntu version is 14.04 Plus Remix, 32 bit.

Thanks for reading,

Gabriele

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/846651/installing-starcraft-2-playonlinux/881411#881411

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've managed to run it on Ubuntu, but I'm having crashing problems and I think because I have the 32 bit version but I don't know..

Comment: do you use PlayonLinux ?