# Starcraft 2 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: wine, games

So far every solution I found for previous versions doesn't work. I've seen that for Ubuntu 18 should work with Wine out the box, but not really. Has someone managed to work it out?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: I've got some progress since I wrote the question. I've managed to install it, but now I just can't run it. I click on Play and nothing happens

Comment: I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846651/installing-starcraft-2-playonlinux), which was originally written for Ubuntu 16.04 but still worked on 18.04. I had to install winbind for the StarCraft 2 installer to complete, although I did not have to do any of the winetricks. Hope this helps.